# How do I proceed in an attempt to find audio files which play the same song but are in different compressed formats?

Tags: java, python, ffmpeg, hidden-markov-models, fuzzy-logic

all i want is suppose i have same song named as song.mp3 and song.aac now i want my program to identify that they are same, i know this is non-trivail task to do.

so far i have tried fingerprinting audio using dejavu python library which produces 2 different fingerprints for our case song.mp3 and song.aac, hence it doesnt suit need of my program.

I also tried MD5 using FFMPEG but as expected it gives different hash for even same songs downloaded from different websites

Do you guys have any idea how do I proceed?
It would be even great to provide me step wise procedure and library to achieve my goal.
thank you

Comment: If you could load both files and substract one wave from the other, then a perfect match would be a "null" wave. Of course, given 2 different formats, I'd expect tiny differences between them. I use a similar method to identify duplicates of images in large sets where they can be saved in different formats.

Comment: How one can get the wave? can you please elaborate on this ? thanks

Comment: You should rather explain more about what you did with the fingerprinting approach. This is the only way to go about solving this problem. Show us some sample files and the code you're using, and what output you get. Or you could use a music recognition service. But that only works if the songs are somehow published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio fingerprinting is incredibly complex, and difficult to get right. You do not really want to come up with your own algorithm just like that, because it likely is much worse than established methods (being better than established methods requires doing some research ;-)).

One of the open source solutions for audio fingerprinting which I found is http://echoprint.me/codegen

You can use that in your application, either by calling directly into the libcodegen API, or by spawning subprocesses for audio analysis.